# Creating a new column based on a condition in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, for-loop

I would like to create a column that repeats the content in Col1 if it starts with "M " until it hits another row that starts with "M " and takes the value of that one and repeats until it hits a new one, and so on because I have many over 50 "M #"s in my real data.

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| M 1: number drug 1 deaths | row |
| background | blah |
| method | blah blah |
| M 2: number drug 2 deaths | row |
| background | blah |
| method | blah blah |

I would like it to look like this:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M 1: number drug 1 deaths | row | M 1: number drug 1 deaths |
| background | blah | M 1: number drug 1 deaths |
| method | blah blah | M 1: number drug 1 deaths |
| M 2: number drug 2 deaths | row | M 2: number drug 2 deaths |
| background | blah | M 2: number drug 2 deaths |
| method | blah blah | M 2: number drug 2 deaths |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to select the value from `Col1` where `Col1` starts with `M`  and then use [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) to fill in the blanks:

```py
df['Col3'] = df['Col1'].where(df['Col1'].str.startswith('M ')).ffill()
```

Output

```
                         Col1       Col2                        Col3
0  M 1: number drug 1 deaths         row  M 1: number drug 1 deaths
1                 background        blah  M 1: number drug 1 deaths
2                     method   blah blah  M 1: number drug 1 deaths
3  M 2: number drug 2 deaths         row  M 2: number drug 2 deaths
4                 background        blah  M 2: number drug 2 deaths
5                     method   blah blah  M 2: number drug 2 deaths
```